# How to make imacro to select/solve the captcha?(RecaptchaV2)

Tags: recaptcha, 2captcha

I edited some code to auto solve recaptcha v2.
I get the numbers from api of 2captcha/9kw and all is perfect!

But after I get the numbers. LIKE: 258
How  can I make each number to select this box?

This is the code I have for this part:
(but its not select the specific numbers, its select all the photos)

Please if someone know how to fix it, please help.

```
'Fill the recognized characters to the verification box (Click the pictures 1..9)

FRAME F=2
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES

SET 1 EVAL("var s=\"{{answer}}\"; if(s.match(/^[0-9]+$/) && s.length <= 9 && s.length >= 2) s.substr(0,1); else MacroError(\"Captcha answer is wrong.\")")
TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/payload?c=*

SET !ERRORIGNORE NO``
```

Answer (score 0):

It's imacros. There is the 9kw API recaptcha v2 example for imacros in javascript and jquery with your features as recaptcha_v2_jquery.js: https://www.9kw.eu/grafik/plugins/9kweu_recaptcha_v2.zip

Then you have the full imacros solution in iim, javascript and javascript with jquery. And you can use any other servies with change few lines.

I cannot quote very long examples (no attachments possible on stackoverflow) and the downloadlink is online since years.

Or you can use imacros with javascript/jquery and then you can check/grab it with javascript. See [iMacros Http POST to API endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36108832/imacros-http-post-to-api-endpoint)

Small snippet to use the answer with your elements as core code with jquery:

```html
var answer = "853";
var myarray = answer.split('');
if(myarray.length > 1){
 for(var i = 0;i < myarray.length; i++){
  if(myarray[i].match(/^[0-9]+$/)){
   myarray[i] = parseFloat(myarray[i]) - 1;
   if(myarray[i] == ""){
    myarray[i] = 0;
   }
   $('iframe').contents().find('html').find(".rc-image-tile-wrapper").eq(myarray[i]).click();
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tried to solve this but I did look into this. You have to use EVENT command and experimental recording. When u send the new recaptcha image to DBC they will send something like this [(4),(1),(2)].

With little JS code and EVENT command you can use the numbers above to click on matching positions of images.

Answer (score -1):

there is the imacros 2captcha API example:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/bmex7ya4xv510jo/Imacros%20API%20Example.zip?dl=0
but does not integrated reportbad feature.